# Don't repeat [Math.floor(Math.random()] random number

Tags: jquery, html

How can i avoid repeating random number in this function  ?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LELGE/25/)

```
var maxImg = 15; 
function hexImgName() {
    var imgSRC = '';
    $(".hexagon-img img").each(function (i) {
        var randomImg = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxImg) + 1; //generate a random number from 0 to 10
        imgSRC = 'img/hex/pic-' + randomImg + '.gif';
        $(this).attr('src', imgSRC);
    });
}
```

I have 15 images in my folder image name pic-1.gif , pic-2.gif  , pic-3.gif  ... pic-15.gif

I am changing img src path via jQuery  `img/hex/pic-' + randomImg + '.gif';`

```
My question
```

I need to different src path on each images but img src path dont repeat

Thanks

Comment: You mean don't have duplicate random number? Your question is unclear imo

Comment: Do you always want to use the same random number? Or what do you expect?

Comment: Create an array with the same size as the number of images, and then Pop (might be `Slice` actually) items at random until the array is empty.

Comment: Great. Perfectly stupid asked question, and "-2" for my possible good answer. Please, tell more information, and ask question in more understandable way. THX.

Comment: PS. Possible answer (good) for such a question is: delete 5 line. Then you also "avoid repeating random number in this function"!!!

Comment: I agree with Jacek, I don't know why people minused his answer.

Comment: @KeluThatsall ya because Jacek was answering the title, so he wasn't wrong...

Comment: Thx. And sorry for language (stupid), I shouldn't comment like this.

Comment: OK, no problem. I will try to help once more then :).

Comment: Ok clear :). Downvoted avoided :). I think Дамян Станчев answer should do the trick.

Comment: Edited with jsfiddle @Jacek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate an array with the required numbers, shuffle it and use it's number one after another:

```
function shuffle(o){
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};

var maxImg = 15;
for (var i = maxImg, a=[]; i--;) a.push(i);
shuffle(a);

function hexImgName() {
    var pos = 0;
    var imgSRC = '';
    $(".hexagon-img img").each(function (i) {
        var randomImg = a[pos++];
        imgSRC = 'img/hex/pic-' + randomImg + '.gif';
        $(this).attr('src', imgSRC);
    });
}
```

You can see an updated version of your JSFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/LELGE/26/

Comment: Edited my question  with jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var grabBag = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

// randomize order of elements with a sort function that randomly returns -1/0/1
grabBag.sort(function(xx,yy){ return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) - 1; })

function getNextRandom(){
    return grabBag.shift();
};

var originalLength = grabBag.length;
for(var i = 0; i < originalLength .length; i++){
    console.log(getNextRandom());
}
```

Comment: Edited my question  with jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

To simply not get the same number consecutively, just do this:

```
var maxImg = 15; 
var lastImg;
function hexImgName() {
    var imgSRC = '';
    $(".hexagon-img img").each(function (i) {
        var randomImg = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxImg) + 1; //generate a random number from 0 to 10;
        while (lastImg==randomImg) {
           randomImg = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxImg) + 1; //generate a random number from 0 to 10;           
        }
        lastImg=randomImg;
        imgSRC = 'img/hex/pic-' + randomImg + '.gif';
        $(this).attr('src', imgSRC);
    });
}
```

Comment: Its repeating bro , and may i ask why downvote  for my question ?

Comment: Edited my question  with jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry, randomImg was out of scope. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jabark/LELGE/28/). This will make the next image different to the previous. Basically it does a while loop and will run until randomImg is different to lastImg. If you want to make EVERY image different, you will need to add the numbers to an array and check if that number is in the array in the while loop. Does that help?